# Flexbox - move middle element to the next line (without media query)

Tags: css, flexbox

What I want to achieve (but without the media query):

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqLezyfe/2/)

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  #wrapper {
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    height: 100px;
  }

  .center {
    width: 100%;
    order: 3;
  }

  .left{
    width: 50%;
  }

  .right {
    width:50%;
    order:2;
  }
}
```

I have 3 elements inside a wrapper, all shrinked. At desktop size, there is some space left over, however when I resize my window to a smaller dimension, at some point, elements run out of space. When that happens, I want to put the middle element to the next line. I have a solution, where the third element goes to the next line, and JSFiddle solution, where the second element goes to the next line, but always at the same static width.

So is it possible to put the middle element to the next line, when all three shrinked elements run out of space?

Comment: When the space is too small, the items will wrap. That can happen naturally. But why would the second and third elements switch at that point? Without a media query, there's nothing telling them to switch.

Comment: Could you clarify why you're trying to avoid media queries?  Because your solution looks like a perfect use case for media queries--changing the order and size of flex children at a given breakpoint.

Comment: I would like them to switch, because the third element is much more natural to be at the top right corner. As far as why I would like to avoid media queries. The width of the middle element varies. There are multiple occasions where this wrapper is shown on the website and each time with different content. So if I set a media query at the maximum length where it should go to the next line, there might be a lot of unnecessary space when the middle element is narrower. The plus side of a media query is the same layout for all the elements at the certain screen size. I'm quite bad at UX.

Comment: You could add a script to check the width of the last element, if the last element is at full screen width you add `order` and `width: 100%;` on the middle-element to place it at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely wrap the line without media queries by using `flex-wrap`, `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` to specify a minimum width that any given item should have:

```
#wrapper{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.right{
  width: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
  order: 3;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 200px;
}
```

But it's not possible to change the `flex-order` based *solely* on whether the elements "fit". For that you definitely need a media query.